# R503 fingerprint sensor

Tags: python, raspberry-pi4, fingerprint, adafruit

I'm working with an R503 fingerprint sensor and a Raspberry Pi, and I'm encountering an issue where I'm receiving a "Failed to Read Data from Sensor" error message.I am using the libraries that adafruit gives you and I am trying to run the fingerprint_r503_rpi.py. I've checked my wiring and connections, ensured that the power supply is stable, and verified the serial communication settings. However, I'm still unable to establish communication with the sensor.

Comment: Can you share the code and the error with us?

Comment: the error code that i am getting is.
"/home/Adafruit_CircuitPython_Fingerprint/examples/adafruit_fingerprint.py", line 349, in _get_packet raise RuntimeError("Failed to read data from sensor")

and the code that i am using you can find here.
https://github.com/adafruit/Adafruit_CircuitPython_Fingerprint/blob/main/examples/fingerprint_r503_rpi.py